# How to get the value of all keys in an array with AppContext (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I have a project where I need to get data from js file and use it in Checkbox.Group (antd).

I’ve been in React for a couple of days and javascript also just didn’t know, help

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Menu, Button,Dropdown, Checkbox } from 'antd'
import {AppContext} from '../../../context/main'

const Name = () => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const {preschool} = useContext(AppContext)
    const menu = (
        <Menu className="dropdown-menu">
            <Checkbox.Group
                // onChange={(v) => setLabels(v)}
                options={preschool.Наименование}
                className="checkboxGroup"
            />
            <Button size="large">Сбросить</Button>
            <Button size="large">Сохранить</Button>
        </Menu>
    )
    return (
        <Dropdown 
            overlay={menu}
            visible={visible}
            onVisibleChange={(val) => setVisible(val)}
        >
            <Button 
                className="button" 
                ghost={true}
            >
                Наименование
            </Button>
        </Dropdown>
    )
}
export default Name
```

it is main.js file

```
const preschool_data = [
  {
    Наименование: 'ГККП "ясли сад №1',
    Язык_Обучения: 'Русский',
    Форма_учереждения: 'Государственная',
    'Проектная мощность': '190',
    'Фактическая наполненность': '240',
    '%': '126%',
    Наполненность: '',
    KPI: 'red',
    Рейтинг: '9.73',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[Object.values()][1]`

> returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values

```js
const preschool_data = {
  Наименование: 'ГККП "ясли сад №1',
  Язык_Обучения: 'Русский',
  Форма_учереждения: 'Государственная',
  'Проектная мощность': '190',
  'Фактическая наполненность': '240',
  '%': '126%',
  Наполненность: '',
  KPI: 'red',
  Рейтинг: '9.73',
};

console.log(Object.values(preschool_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you're getting?

Just in case, check these:

1) Make sure `AppContext` refers to the context and not the provider:

```
const AppContext = createContext()
```

2) In your provider, make sure it's `value` and not `valueS`:

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ preschool }}>
```